# Why isn't the Facebook 'switch profile' option visible on my account?

Tags: facebook, profile

I have my personal FB profile (don't really use it) but I'm admin to 2 groups.  When posting as admin in the groups, FB does not give me the option to switch profiles.  I've troubleshooted all the usual things to check.  No option to add a linked page in settings, no option to choose a different profile top RHS, and meta verified with no option to add account other than instagram.  So essentially, every post I make in the groups is showing as me personally posting and not the admin...super frustrating!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean "option to switch profiles"? Do you have a Facebook Page? Are you looking to use the Facebook Page as the author of group posts? Have you already reviewed the Facebook Help? If so, why the official help doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: @wicket yes I have a Facebook page + admin 2 FB group pages, and yes, already reviewed FB help and other google sources.  I don't know why the 'offical help' doesn't help my needs, that why I asked here on this forum!  Option to switch profiles is a feature when posting to choose between personal profile and group admin, which I thought folk on here might already know about.